# Numbering cells in a table

Tags: tables, positioning

In the output below, I would like to put my red square at a better place (this is to explain how a table has been filled). The space from the red box to the vertical rule should be the same as the space from the red box to the horizontal rule. Is there an easy way to do this?

[image]

Here is the code used with a wobbly code for my macro. I plead guilty.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}

\newcommand\when[1]{%
    \hfill $\color{red}{}^{\fbox{\tiny #1}^{\vphantom{X}}}$}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{|p{2.5cm}}}
            & Magie
            & Théâtre
            & Photo
            & Total \\
    \hline
    Adultes & \when{4}
            & \when{6}
            & \when{5}
            & \when{1} \\
    \hline
    Enfants & \when{3}
            & \when{8}
            & Value  \when{7}
            & \when{2} \\
    \hline
    Total   & \when{9}
            & \when{10}
            & \when{11}
            & Total
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "better place"? Could you add some details about your requirements?

Comment: My question has been updated to talk about vertical and horizontal spacing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simon Dispa’s answer is very effective. However, it can be improved.

I’d reduce the `\fboxsep` for the small rectangles and set a precise separation from the top and the right: the box is first lowered to have zero height, then raised to the height of a strut minus 1pt. A space of 1pt is added to the right.

The added space is finally removed for the last column.

I use the `w` column type, which seems better than `p` for this application.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\when[1]{%
  \hfill
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-1pt}{%
    \raisebox{-\height}{%
      \setlength{\fboxsep}{1.5pt}%
      \textcolor{red}{\fbox{\tiny #1}\hspace{1pt}}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{|w{l}{2.5cm}@{}}@{\hspace{-1pt}}}
            & Magie
            & Théâtre
            & Photo
            & Total \\
    \hline
    Adultes & \when{4}
            & \when{6}
            & \when{5}
            & \when{1} \\
    \hline
    Enfants & \when{3}
            & \when{8}
            & Value  \when{7}
            & \when{2} \\
    \hline
    Total   & \when{9}
            & \when{10}
            & \when{11}
            & Total
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I choose this answer because of the cleaner macro `\when`. Thanks for this proposition.

Answer (score 6):

Suppressing the right tab column separation.

[image: a]

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}

\newcommand\when[1]{%
    \hfill $\color{red}{}^{\fbox{\tiny #1}^{\vphantom{X}}}$}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tabular}{l*{4}{|p{2.5cm}@{}}}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        & Magie
        & Théâtre
        & Photo
        & Total \\
        \hline
        Adultes & \when{4}
        & \when{6}
        & \when{5}
        & \when{1} \\
        \hline
        Enfants & \when{3}
        & \when{8}
        & Value  \when{7}
        & \when{2} \\
        \hline
        Total   & \when{9}
        & \when{10}
        & \when{11}
        & Total
    \end{tabular}
    
\end{document}
```

There is still a very small difference that can be reduced (for this font size) using for example

`\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{|p{2.5cm}@{\hspace{0.2pt}}}}`

[image: c]

Comment: Easy way and the output looks good. Thanks for this simple solution.